# Dropdown Conditional ListItem ASP VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

So I have an ASP page that I'm working on and on this page there is a dropdown list and a button (amongst other things, but these are whats important) The dropdown list selects a location of a store, and the button on this page that brings up a pop-up window for the user to do things. On this pop-up page there is a dropdown menu that has 4 options: "kiosk, alert 1, alert 2, and alert 3". Not all stores has kiosks though. So I need to find a way to have "kiosk" not show up as a dropdown list item if the store does not have a kiosk. I know how to get the code to check if the store has a kiosk or not. I just don't know how to change the dropdown list to not include the "kiosk" item. Is this something I do in the ASP code? Or the page_load of the codebehind (VB.Net)? Or is this javascript? Please excuse me, but I am very new to ASP, this is my first project. Thank you guys so much!

ASP For The Dropdown List

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="stateDropDownList" AutoPostBack="true" style="align-content:center; margin-left:200px" width="100px"  runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" disabled="disabled" Value=""> Email Lists </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="kiosk"> Kiosk </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="alert1"> Alert 1 </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="alert2"> Alert 2 </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="alert3"> Alert 3 </asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: You have a few different options.  You can create you DropDownList dynamically, so that way in the code-behind if you know Kiosk is an option then when you create the DropDownList you add it, or you dont.  Another way is to remove the ListItem from the DropDownList.  Something like ````stateDropDownList.Items.RemoveAt(0)```` or whatever index the Kiosk will be at.

Comment: Thanks! I'm definitely going to go with the RemoveAt one, since the list is already all set up. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few simple examples of how you can hide the ListItem on Page_Load

HTML

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="_testPW22.aspx.vb" Inherits="_testPW22" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

           <asp:DropDownList ID="stateDropDownList" AutoPostBack="true" style="align-content:center; margin-left:200px" width="100px"  runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" disabled="disabled" Value=""> Email Lists </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="kiosk"> Kiosk </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="alert1"> Alert 1 </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="alert2"> Alert 2 </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="alert3"> Alert 3 </asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code-behind

```
Imports System.Linq

Partial Class _testPW22
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Class Store
        Public Property HasKiosk As Boolean = False
    End Class

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        ' Load up your Store object, or whatever object it is you are using to determine if it has a Kiosk
        Dim store As New Store()

        If Not store.HasKiosk Then

            ' Option 1 if you know the index
            stateDropDownList.Items.RemoveAt(1)

            ' Opton 2 - you need to count down to 0 in order to remove from the collection you are iterating through
            For i As Integer = stateDropDownList.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If String.Equals(stateDropDownList.Items(i).Value, "Kiosk", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                    stateDropDownList.Items.RemoveAt(i)
                End If
            Next

            ' Option 3 - fancy LINQ
            ' Make sure list item exists first, and then remove it
            If stateDropDownList.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)().Any(Function(r) String.Equals(r.Value, "Kiosk", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) Then
                stateDropDownList.Items.Remove(stateDropDownList.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)().FirstOrDefault(Function(r) String.Equals(r.Value, "Kiosk", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            End If


        End If



    End Sub

End Class
```

And then if you wanted to do it dynamically, you could use this example. I use PlaceHolders when I'm adding dynamic controls.  There are a few different ways to add ListItems referenced below.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="DropDownListPlaceHolder" runat="server" />

 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        ' Load up your Store object, or whatever object it is you are using to determine if it has a Kiosk
        Dim store As New Store()

        Dim ddl As New DropDownList()
        ddl.ID = "TestID"
        ddl.AutoPostBack = True
        ddl.Style.Add("align-content", "center")
        ddl.Width = New Unit(100)

        Dim li As New ListItem("EmaiL Lists", String.Empty)
        li.Selected = True
        li.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled")
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, li)

        ddl.Items.Insert(1, New ListItem("Alert 1", "1"))
        ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem("Alert 2", "2"))

        If store.HasKiosk Then
            ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem("Kiosk", "2"))
        End If
End Sub
```